# Python: invalid syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error

Why am I having a 'invalid syntax' error on this script? I'm using the Python 3.3.2 Shell and when I'm trying to run the module there is just an 'invalid syntax' popping up.

```
import os, re, csv
import email, email.message, email.header

MAILDIR = 'mails'
FEATURES = ['from', 'domain', 'ip', 'country', 'content-type', 'charset', 'reply', 'recipients', 'images', 'urls']

try:
    geoip = False
    import pygeoip
    gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoIP.dat', pygeoip.MEMORY_CACHE)
    geoip = True
except ImportError:
    pass
except IOError:
    print 'GeoIP.dat not found'

class Mail(email.message.Message):
    def count_html_tag(self, tag):
        tags = 0
        for part in email.iterators.typed_subpart_iterator(self, 'text', 'html'):
            html = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            tags += html.lower().count('<' + tag)
        return tags

def feature(self, feature):
    # content-type: plain, html, multipart
    if feature == 'content-type':
        if self.is_multipart():
            return 'multipart'
        else:
            return self.get_content_subtype()

    # charset: list of charsets (if multipart)
    elif feature == 'charset':
        return ','.join(sorted(set(self.get_charsets()) - {None}))

    # from: claimed email address of sender
    elif feature == 'from':
        addr = self.get('from', self.get('sender', ''))
        return email.utils.parseaddr(addr)[1]

    # domain: domain name of sender
    elif feature == 'domain':
        return self.feature('from').split('@', 1)[1]

    # ip: possible ip address of sender
    elif feature == 'ip':
        if 'x-original-ip' in self:
            return self['x-original-ip']
        else:
            for received in reversed(self.get_all('received')):
                m = re.search('\[([0-9.]*)\]', received)
                if m and m.group(1)[:3] not in ('127', '192', '172', '10.'):
                    return m.group(1)
            else:
                return ''

    # country: country of sender, based on ip
    elif feature == 'country':
        if geoip:
            ip = self.feature('ip')
            return gi.country_code_by_addr(ip) if ip else ''
        else:
            return ''

    # recipient: number of known recipients
    elif feature == 'recipients':
        fields = ('to', 'cc', 'resent-to', 'resent-cc')
        return sum(len(email.utils.getaddresses(self.get_all(field, []))) for field in fields)

    # reply: re, fw
    elif feature == 'reply':
        subject = email.header.decode_header(self.get('Subject', ''))[0][0]
        m = re.match('(re|fw)d?:', subject.lower())
        return m.group(1) if m else ''

    # images: number of images in html
    elif feature == 'images':
        return self.count_html_tag('img')

    # images: number of urls in html
    elif feature == 'urls':
        return self.count_html_tag('a')

    else:
        raise KeyError()

def features(self, lst=FEATURES):
    return {feature: self.feature(feature) for feature in lst}

def main():
    with open('features.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, FEATURES)
        writer.writeheader()
        for mpath in os.listdir(MAILDIR):
            with open(os.path.join(MAILDIR, mpath)) as mfile:
                mail = email.message_from_file(mfile, Mail)
            writer.writerow(mail.features(FEATURES))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance! I'm kinda new on Python

Comment: You know, the error message ALSO tells you where the error is. (You, in contrast, do not tell us where the error is.)

Comment: @Ben As a rule of thumb, whenever it comes to python 3, I always check where they put in print! :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On line 16:

```
...
except IOError:
    print 'GeoIP.dat not found'  # Print is a function
```

This should be `print(....)`